# R - TablePlot() - Clarifications

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I'm just trying to understand how to read table plots. I don't understand what the dividing line in a numerical columns/variable represents. For example, the dividing black line in P1/2/3/4/5 here:

https://steemitimages.com/DQmeEJ8RyPkdRhdqX6CwNsUTzXfGWt36RwyFrixt6NNbPTw/tabplot.PNG

Also, I understand the Y Axis represents proportions (0% to 100%).  Does the X axis for each variable represent proportions too or is that just regular values for the data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure, but those look like boxplots (but they're not.. see below). A classic boxplot will have a central marker for the median and then box ends are at a point called hinges that are set by the first and third interquartile points. You can read up about it at `?boxplot.stats`. It's also possible that someone chose a different statistic to form the x-bounds for those boxes, but we can be certain that they are not proportions since some of them are negative.

The proportions in the "y-axis" are for the various regions. You will need to find documentation to determine the sequence of the regions. I suspect they are viticulture regions in Italy.

Here is a copy of part of the help page: ?tableplot:

> numMode
>   character value that determines how numeric values are plotted. The value consists of the following building blocks, which are concatenated with the "-" symbol. The default value is "mb-sdb-sdl". Prior to version 1.2, "MB-ML" was the default value.
>
> sdb sd bars between mean-sd to mean+sd are shown
>
> sdl sd lines at mean-sd and mean+sd are shown
>
> mb mean bars are shown
>
> MB mean bars are shown, where the color of the bar indicate completeness where positive mean values are blue and negative orange
>
> ml mean lines are shown
>
> ML mean lines are shown, where positive mean values are blue and negative orange
>
> mean2 mean values are shown

This default value for numMode obviously changed since most of the example in the documentation only show the mean value.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understand it's a tableplot() and am not sure if they can have a boxplot marker within each column for that function. I see in the same in the diamonds dataset - does this update your answer?  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tabplot/vignettes/tabplot-vignette.html